# Replacing duplicates (pandas to csv or hdf5 or sql)?

Tags: pandas, sqlite, hdfs

I am using pandas to process information. The current work flow is to read the last 30 days of data from a hdf5 file, then add the latest data to it and perform some analysis.

I then need to append this data back to the original hdf5 file (with a column indicating whether the same Customer_ID showed up multiple times). The only problem is that there are duplicates. The only solution I have is to read the whole file into memory, drop the duplicates, and then write the file all over again (replacing it completely). Is there a way to avoid appending duplicate data? Like an 'insert and replace' command that I can use in pandas?

```
querydate = dt.date.today() - Timedelta(30, unit='d')
df = pd.read_hdf(loc+hdfname, 'Raw', where = [('Report_Date > querydate')])
df2 = pd.read_csv(loc+yesterdayfile.csv)
combine = [df,df2]
df3 = pd.concat(combine)
```

I need to see if the latest data (from yesterday) existed previously (within a 30 day rolling window). Below you can see that I append the latest data to the original file, I then read that file into memory, drop duplicates, then write it again (overwriting the existing file)

```
hdf = HDFStore(loc+hdfname)
hdf.put('Raw', df3, format= 'table', complib= 'blosc', complevel=5, data_columns = True, append = True)

df = pd.read_hdf(loc+hdfname, 'Raw')
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Emp_ID', 'Interaction_Time', 'Customer_ID'], take_last = True, inplace = True)

hdf = HDFStore(loc+hdfname)
hdf.put('Raw', df, format= 'table', complib= 'blosc', complevel=5, data_columns = True, append = False)
```